# How to use document vectors in isolationforest in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gensim, outliers, doc2vec

In understanding what `isolation forest` really does, I did a sample project as follows using 8 features as follows.

```
from sklearn.ensemble import IsolationForest    
#features
df_selected = df[["feature1", "feature2", "feature3", "feature4", "feature5", "feature6", "feature7", "feature8"]]
X = np.array(df_selected)

#isolation forest
clf = IsolationForest(max_samples='auto', random_state=42, behaviour="new", contamination=.01)
clf.fit(X)
y_pred_train = clf.predict(X)

print(np.where(y_pred_train == -1)[0])
```

Now, I want to identify what are the *outlier documents* using `isolation forest`. For that I trained a `doc2vec` model using `gensim`. Now for each of my document in the dataset I have a `300-dimensional vector`.

My question is can I straight away use the document vectors in `isolation forest` as `X` in the above code to detect outliers? Or do I need to reduce the dimensionality of the vectors before applying them to `isolation forest`?

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: Did you try using the 300-dimensional doc-vectors as your new `X`? What are the results of trying that? I'm not sure `IsolationForest` will work well on 'dense' embeddings like `Doc2Vec`, as it appears to operate on individual features (dimensions) as if they were individually interpretable – which isn't usually the case (as opposed to arbitrary non-axis-aligned directions, or neighborhoods, in the embedding space). But, it might work, and the best way to find out is to try it & analyze/report the results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can straight away use the `predict()` to detect outliers unless you plan on removing some variables that would not be considered in the training model.

In general, I would say to do a correlation analysis and remove the variables that are highly correlated with each other (Logic basis being that if they are highly correlated, then they are the same and should not encourage the bias of the variables by doubling the consideration).

Feel free to dispute otherwise or state your considerations as I think the above is really my opinion on how to approach the problem.